# What's the easiest way to set bit flags in an enum?

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to do this, and it's quite tedious to do.

```
enum class GUIEventEnum : uint64 {
    NONE = 0,
     
    CURSOR_LMB_DOWN = 1 << 1, 
    CURSOR_LMB_UP = 1 << 2,
    CURSOR_LMB_CLICK = 1 << 3,
    CURSOR_RMB_DOWN = 1 << 4,
    CURSOR_RMB_UP = 1 << 5,
    CURSOR_RMB_CLICK = 1 << 6,
    CURSOR_MMB_DOWN = 1 << 7,
    CURSOR_MMB_UP = 1 << 8,
    CURSOR_MMB_CLICK = 1 << 9,
    CURSOR_SCROLL = 1 << 10,
};
```

And there are going to be many more. Is there a way I can just declare this in a list? like enums?

Comment: If you want enumeration constants to have specific values (that doesn't follow the scheme used by default for enumerations) then you *must* explicitly specify the values.

Comment: Depending on the use case you could create a class that wraps a `uint64_t` and allocates flags (in a `static map`) when needed, which would circumvent this issue, but it will not be an enum at that point.

Comment: Abstract it? If your "flags" is a class object, you can nest the (sequential) enumerators and overload `operator|` to do `1 << E` before it applies a fundamental bitwise OR.

Comment: After all, if you use a scoped enumeration you'll have to do a bunch of overloading anyway (or **a lot** of casting).

Comment: "*And there are going to be many more.*" If that's true, maybe a bitfield isn't what you need. Maybe you just need to send multiple events, each with its own value.

Comment: @NicolBolas If it's not a bitfield then how would a filter work? So for example if a listener is listening to RMB_DOWN | MOUSE_MOVE | SCROLL_WHEEL_UP, if it's not a bitfield this would be a loop required?

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*if it's not a bitfield this would be a loop required*" Yeah. So what? The performance of your application is not going to turn on testing an integer against 3 integers in a loop when you're figuring out where to send an event.

Comment: @NicolBolas Three integers? What I mean is if you have 36 flags/bits, and you have an event message, and you have a filter, or a listener that filters messages of certain types, let's just say it listens to all events except three, this seems a perfectly ideal situation for a bitfield, isn't it? One bitwise operation to basically to check 36 values. If it's not a bitfield what's the next best thing? A loop? I don't know why you say only 3 integers, did you assume I'd have an event system with only 3 event types?

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*I don't know why you say only 3 integers*" Because you gave an example where you were listening to 3 events. Such a listener would therefore have a loop over those 3 integers to check to see if it should look at any given event. How many events are possible is irrelevant; what matters is how many events a given listener will look for.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's interesting when you say that a listener will "look for" an event, because I intended to broadcast an event and immediately send out those to the listeners, the broadcaster/publisher calls a handler function on all listeners to let them know the event happened. The listener doesn't "look for" the publication/broadcast. On the other hand the other system I thought of was to first publish/broadcast, and then later in the code have the listener search the broadcasts/publications. Is that the one you had in mind? Are both of them good options?

Answer (score 1):

If every enumerator is going to have its own bit, then you can write a `constexpr` function to compute the bit from the enumerator in question:

```
constexpr inline std::uint64_t event_bit(GUIEventEnum e)
{
  return 0x1 << static_cast<std::uint64_t>(e);
}
```